# Offline language detection library or script

Tags: library, python, language, nlp

One of my Python services was using [textblob](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/) for language detection. Last month Google made a [breaking change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69338699/httperror-http-error-404-not-found-while-using-translation-function-in-textb) to the API service which textblob was calling. Steps have been provided on SO to update textblob to make it work again. But I have decided that I want my service to not be vulnerable to third-party breaking changes. I am therefore looking for an offline solution.

This is the function in question as it is currently. Not much to it:

```
def is_english(text):
    blob = TextBlob(text)
    language = blob.detect_language()
    return language == "en"
```

The solution should:

1. Be capable of determining whether a page of text (~~300 words) is written in English or not (just True/False. If it isn't English I don't particularly care what language it is, I'm just dropping it).
2. Be capable of working without an internet connection.
3. Be either a Python library or a script/app that can run on a Linux OS and be called from the CLI.
4. May use ML models but could also just be a library that checks the text against an English word corpus and returns False if not enough of the words are English.

If this doesn't exist I could probably write the corpus checker in (4) above myself but I'd rather use something if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`polyglot` library](https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot#language-detection) has a Language Detection package [`polyglot.detect`](https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Detection.html#language-detection) that seems to fit your requirements perfectly:

> 1. Be capable of determining whether a page of text (~~300 words) is written in English or not (just True/False. If it isn't English I don't p3articularly care what language it is, I'm just dropping it).

Looking at the [introductory example](https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Detection.html#example) polyglot returns the best match using only 2 lines so you can immediately test for English.

> 2. Be capable of working without an internet connection.

After installing polyglot locally you can use it offline.

> 3. Be either a Python library or a script/app that can run on a Linux OS and be called from the CLI.

polyglot is a Python library and [can be installed on Linux](https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation.html#dependencies). It also has a convenient [CLI](https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/CLI.html).

> 4. May use ML models but could also just be a library that checks the text against an English word corpus and returns False if not enough of the words are English.

[polyglot depends](https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Detection.html#language-detection) on *"[CLD2](https://github.com/CLD2Owners/cld2) is a Naïve Bayesian classifier"* that comes with *"table-driven scoring is highly optimized for both space and speed, running about 10x faster than other detectors and covering over 70 languages in 1.8MB of x86 code and tables"*. So there's no need for an additional corpus because the necessary tables com built-in.